# A visual perception of time

Tags: physics

So I'm creating a character that is an extradimensional being that exists outside of time. If we experience time as a linear event, how would time be perceived if this being has the ability to see time in a way that we look at how people move through three dimensions.

I was initially going to base it off of how Dr. Manhattan perceives time (simultaneously happening but unable to directly affect it), but the character I'm creating also has the ability to manipulate time for other individuals.

I forgot where I read it, but if a being were to perceive time for an individual, the person would look like a massive worm. The "head" is where the person ends up and the "tail" of the worm would be where the person comes from.

Would that be an accurate representation of how an extradimensional being would perceive time for individuals?

Comment: There's an incredible number of options, but you may be able to narrow it down by explaining what particular ways the character can manipulate time.  People tend to visualize things in ways which they can use, so the visualization would likely line up with their particular approach.  For example, one might see time as a spinning pot if you can make coarse changes, but nothing exact.  You might see it as a Rube Goldberg device if you can make single discrete changes, but no broad strokes.

Comment: Have you watched Star Trek: DS9?  You are describing the wormhole aliens.

Comment: Another question: can they perceive themselves?  If so, then they can perceive their own ability to perceive the future, and that sort of self-reference encourages certain patterns to form.

Answer (score 4):

Although this may not be the answer you are wanting to hear, I think it's plausible that such an entity might have mental or sensory "faculties" that we as humans do not possess. Our evolution as primates in our world has led us to perceive space-time as 3 dimensions of space and one of linear time. And so the senses and cognitive abilities we have words for are calibrated to that style of perception.

However, an entity evolving in say 5 dimensions, where past, present and future can be viewed simultaneously might very well have sensory and cognitive abilities we don't have analogs for, just as we cannot easily envision what ultraviolet colors look like to animals that can see them.

I think there is quite a lot of room for an author to define how the entity sees objects and I don't know of any scientific reason someone could cite to disprove your claim, as long as you make it plausible, and I think your idea of the worm-looking thing is a logically valid enough idea that you could imagine things in ways that could be plausible. If you come up with specific ideas, ask on this site to see if people like the idea, that could give you feedback about how a general fan-base might react to your ideas.

Comment: The "worm-looking thing" is one way of imagining a person's worldline. Part of the block universe concept and how worldlines might look as they run through it.

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to avoid using "dimension" to mean something else. Generally, creatures from other "dimensions" means creatures from other universes (which may or may not share the same physics as ours). It's pretty easy to imagine a 1-dimensional world, same with 2-d --as long as time is tacked on. A creature which doesn't experience time, can't change *by definition*.

There have been attempts to invent mathematical universes with more than one time-like dimension, but they've been self-contradictory and the efforts have, so far, failed. I personally like the idea of 5 dimensions, with the 5th being probability. Physicists often work with 3n or 6n or 10, 11, or 20n spaces, when n is the number of distinct particles or points in that space. So, "dimension" doesn't mean the same thing even among Physicists.

A being not moving through time, can't move. But. Einstein (I think, but don't quote me) used the concept of a loaf of bread with raisins in it to describe space-time. each raisin is an event - which is the combination of a particular point in space with a particular instant in time.

If you think of a loaf of bread, then you can picture threads running through it. For instance your thread began the moment you were conceived and continues till your death. The atoms in your body all began either during the big bang, or perhaps during stellar nucleosynthesis and their threads all converged - at one time or another on the space-time which you occupy (and of course, most of those threads leave after seconds, minutes, hours, days, or years and then go their separate ways).

What Einstein's special relativity says is that the way you slice up that bread loaf can and does vary. If we think of each slice as "an instant", then it's possible two raisins exist in that same slice, but cut the loaf on a different slant, and the two raisins are in different slices. In fact in some slants, one raisin will "come first" and in some it will "come after" the other raisin.

Before and After are relative terms, and there is no absolute meaning to the term "now". OK, so with that (probably just confusing) explanation.

Let's avoid Special Relativity, and just think of space-time as a flip-book. You know what a flip-book is? There's a picture on each page, and when you flip through the pages, the picture seems to move - to be animated.

So let's make a flip book, and make each page a cell (a frame, a still) from a movie - instead of flat, they're put into a book, front to back. And the size is, well, as big as your imagination can make it.

You and I travel thru it in a "straight line" front to back. Think of this as drilling a hole thru the center of the book, front to back. But someone else can drill a hole at a different angle, back to front, or even a worm-hole which meanders around. Maybe across one page (one instant for us) and then diagonally through a bunch more before reversing direction and maybe looping around a few times. This might be a useful way to think about a creature who could travel through space-time in any way it wished.

Comment: I encourage you to add some paragraphs.  The “wall of text” is hard to read.

Comment: +1 for the basic observation that "a being not moving through time can't move".

Answer (score 0):

To help describe this physically I'd recommend finding and read "Flat Land".

A summary in 2D to 3D;

A 2D entity sees their world as just lines, being unable to peer into the 3rd spacial dimension. A 3D entity looking on a 2D world sees the shape of 2D formations. When a 3D entity interacts with a 2D entity, the 2D entity can only perceive their 2D manifestation.

Time complicates this but you can take two routes;

Space-Time is one Dimension - which allows any n-D spatial dimensions to include time without incrementing the value of 'n'. This is the scientific understanding of time and an external observer sees a static unchanging universe, which brings up quantum entanglement because those inside this universe do not perceive it as static. So a good description could be they see our universe as a sphere with a radius the lifetime of the universe with everything that is, has been or will be filling it.

Time is its own dimension separate from the three spatial dimensions - our 3D universe is then truly a 4D universe that a 5D entity would perceive all of time as a boundary within our universe that we see as linear, perhaps as a thin plate the length of the life of the universe with everything that is, has been or will be on its surface.